# Jquery ignore elements with "disabled" class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery and creating event handlers like this:

```
$('#some_selector a.add').live('click', function(){...});
```

However, I need to **not execute** handlers when an element has `disabled` class. Then I wrote the following to achieve this:

```
$('#some_selector a.add:not(.disabled)').live('click', function(){...});
```

But I'm tired of watching over all the places that I need to add `:not(.disabled)`, sometimes I forget to add it and so on. Moreover, if I have an anchor element and my handler prevents default action on it, than adding `:not(.disabled)` will cause browser to open next page instead of doing nothing.

So is there a way to set up automatic disabling on handler execution when an element meets some condition (like having "disabled" class)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

First, bind an event handler to the `.disabled` elements which prevents other handlers to be executed and prevents the default action:

```
$('#some_selector a.add.disabled').live('click', function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Then you can bind your other event handlers as you did before. As event handlers are executed in the order they have been bound, the event handler for `disabled` elements will always execute first and prevent other handlers from executing (through [`stopImmediatePropagation` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VEb9x/)

Comment: Nice trick! But I can't understand how it is guaranteed that this handler will be executed first? I tried to use just ``event.stopPropagation()`` and ``event.preventDefault()`` but it did not work that way.

Comment: @dragoon: `stopPropagation` will not work because of the way `live` works. The order of execution is guarantee by jQuery. I cannot tell you how exactly they are doing this, but the source is freely available ;) Anwyays, you really should consider @mu's answer, which is semantically more correct.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `<button>` instead of `<a>` for this. A [`<button>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html) with the [`disabled` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fe-disabled) set will not respond to clicks at all:

> A form control that is disabled must prevent any `click` events that are queued on the user interaction task source from being dispatched on the element.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/sCv8n/

You can style a `<button>` to look pretty much any way you want too.

Comment: Thanks, good solution, but unfortunately, there is an unknown amount of work need to be done to replace all my anchors (check css, refactor selectors), but I'll keep this in mind for future.

Comment: @dragoon: I figured as much but thought it was worth mentioning anyway. Shame that reality keeps getting in the way correctness :)